# Tail-recursive list of divisors of an integer in prolog

Tags: prolog, tail-recursion

I am trying to  make a simple tail-recursive loop to collect the divisors of an integer, divisors(N,List) and its working when List is not instantiated, for example,

```
?- divisors(14,What).
What = [2, 7] ?
```

And I can verify that the wrong list is not the list of divisors,

```
?- divisors(14,[2, 8]).
no
```

Unless I try to verify that [] is not the list, this unfortunately succeeds:

```
?- divisors(14,[]).
true
```

can see in the debugger why it is erroneously succeeding, but I don't see how to fix this:

```
divisors_aux(1,_,L,L).
divisors_aux(D,N,List,Aux) :- D>1,0 is N mod D,D1 is D-1,
                              divisors_aux(D1,N,List,[D|Aux]).
divisors_aux(D,N,List,Aux) :- D>1,D1 is D-1,divisors_aux(D1,N,List,Aux).

divisors(N,List) :- N>1,nonvar(N),D is N-1,divisors_aux(D,N,List,[]).
```

I know there are looping approaches (foreach, etc.) but I am trying to make this "brute force" approach work based on what I have learned so far (roughly first 100 pages of Covington et. al.)

Thanks.

Comment: There is a faster method at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Proper_divisors#Prolog

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when the second clause of `divisors_aux/3` fails (or if it succeeds and you ask for another solution) it will always backtrack to the third clause.

You may want to guard the third clause with `\+(0 is N mod D)` so that it fails when the current number is a divisor of N.

Or alternatively join both clauses with an if-then-else construct:

```
divisors_aux(1,_,L,L).
divisors_aux(D,N,List,Aux) :- D>1,
                              (0 is N mod D -> Aux1=[D|Aux] ; Aux1=Aux),
                              D1 is D-1,
                              divisors_aux(D1,N,List,Aux1).

divisors(N,List) :- N>1,nonvar(N),D is N-1,divisors_aux(D,N,List,[]).
```

Comment: yes, thanks!  Adding \+(0 is N mod D) was exactly what was needed (I haven't read about if-then-else yet, so that will have to wait : )